# SMB File share is reachable through ping but its not accessible from file explorer

Tags: firewall, network-shares, windows-server-2012, azure, smb

A specific SMB share hosted on an Azure VM used to be accessible from File Explorer on all on-premises servers, however the share is no longer accessible on almost all servers, even though no changes in configuration have occurred and it is reachable via `ping` *(from a few servers, I can access the share and its contents)*.

What could cause these kind of issues and what are possible solutions?

Comment: Is the share being accessed by IP or hostname, and if the latter, does pinging the hostname from a non-working client complete successfully? Something changed somewhere, but if no changes were made to the clients unable to access the share, and no changes were made to the Azure VM, have the router and client firewall logs been checked? More information will likely be needed, such as the error that occurs when trying to access the share, verifying the router isn't blocking the traffic _(server and client side if they use different routers)_, firewall and server/client share logs, etc.

Comment: Would using the full UNC path in a shortcut be acceptable in your circumstances? That tends to be more reliable than File Explorer's Network access.